# ECS Service deregistering tasks randomly and not giving exact reason why?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ecs, aws-application-load-balancer

I have an ECS service and task running along with a load balancer. The service is performing well but it randomly de-registers task and restart the task without giving any exact reason.

I go to event logs then I can only see these logs which are not sufficient for me to diagnose the issue:

```
service Auth-Service deregistered 3 targets in target-group Auth-service
service Auth-Service, taskSet ecs-svc/7xxxxxxxxx9) has begun draining connections on 3 tasks.
```

These event logs have no description why ecs service started draining. Can someone suggest me a good way to troubleshoot the issue?

**EDIT**
CPU Utilization Behavior
[CPU Utilization](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZIpKi.png)

I am using envoy proxy and received these logs right before the termination:

```
[2023-06-06 21:34:07.746][1][warning] [AppNet Agent] [Envoy process 15] Additional Exit data: [Core Dump: false][Normal Exit: false][Process Signalled: true]
[2023-06-06 21:34:07.746][1][warning] [AppNet Agent] [Envoy process 15] Exited with code [-1]
2023-06-06T21:34:07Z [Info] Got shutdown signal: terminated (this is cloudwatch agent log)
2023-06-06T21:34:07Z I! [agent] Stopping running outputs (cloudwatch agent)
Application is shutting down... (my application container log)
```

I haven't seen any unusual requests or behavior before shutting down the application. It automatically shuts down. I don't know what's going on.

Comment: If it is deregistering 3 tasks at once, then something has triggered an ECS deployment. I can't think of any other reason that would happen. Unless you are using Spot EC2 instances perhaps?

Comment: No I am not using Spot instances. I am using AWS Fargate.

Comment: Fargate has spot instances also. Are you using those? If you aren't using spot instances, I can't think of any other reason that multiple tasks would be deregistered at once, other than a new deployment being triggered.

Comment: No spot instances used. Whenever I check cpu utilization it reaches 100 percent, but I also implemented auto-scaling on it which isn't working either. 1vCPU is assigned for the task which is good to run my application. I don't know why all of the sudden my cpu utilization cross 100 percent.

Comment: I have added a screenshot of cpu utilization behavior it suddenly goes up, and then tasks de-registration happens.

Comment: Check for something like a batch event which might be happening at same time. Another thing is if CPU reaches 100 it would mean if the ECS scheduler is hitting the container for healthcheck it wont be returned and probably will time out. Consecutive 2 healthcheck failure would mark the container as unhealthy and would start draining.

Comment: Do the container logs not show anything interesting in the period that the CPU spikes?

Comment: Not really. It has simple logs that don't show any unusual behavior.

Comment: You'll need to look into why the CPU is spiking. If this is something like a public web server application then perhaps you are getting slammed by bot requests or something. Regardless, you probably need to add more logging so you can understand what the CPU spikes are.

Comment: I am using envoy proxy and I received these logs that you can see in the question edit. @MarkB

Comment: Those logs just show that ECS sent the shutdown signal to the task, probably because the task was being unresponsive.